# Show that the estimator of the mean is independent of the estimator of the variance in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to illustrate with R the fact that if X1, ..., Xn are random Gaussian variables N(μ, σ^2), then the estimator of the mean (X1 + ... + Xn)/n is independent of the estimator of the variance ((X1-μ)^2 + ... (Xn-μ)^2))/n.

I have established that mathematically with the Cochran's theorem.
Now with R, I'm introducing

```
x = rnorm(50, 3, 1) #50 N(3,1) random variables for instance.
piX1 = rep_len(mean(x), 50) #(this gives me a 50-length vector containing mean(x) 
piX2 = rep_len(x - mean(x), 50)
tab1 = table(piXV1, piXV2)
chi = chisq.test(tab1)
```

This give me a p-value of 1, which makes me skeptical as to whether the Chi Square test actually tests if piX1 and piX2 are independent.. Can anyone tell me if it's actually working?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The code below generates 10000 independent samples and calculates mean and variance. Then, a test on Pearson's correlation between mean and variance estimates was applied.

```
mnvr <- sapply(1:10000, function(k) {
  x = rnorm(50, 3, 1)
  mn <- mean(x)
  vr <- var(x)
  return(c(mn,vr))
})

cor.test(mnvr[1,], mnvr[2,])

#         Pearson's product-moment correlation
# 
# data:  mnvr[1, ] and mnvr[2, ]
# t = -0.001029, df = 9998, p-value = 0.9992
# alternative hypothesis: true correlation is not equal to 0
# 95 percent confidence interval:
#  -0.01961036  0.01958978
# sample estimates:
#          cor 
# -1.02906e-05
```

Comment: Can we do a chis.test in this case instead of a cor.test?

Comment: Mean and variance are continuous random variables, not categorical.